# Run tensorflow through SSH

Tags: tensorflow

When I run tensorflow training code through SSH, I got the following error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

This happens most likely due to summary object saving the models. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try X11forwarding using `-Y` flag, e.g.:

```
ssh -Y user@server
```

Comment: I have that, but still got error. I tried export DISPLAY=:0.0 after ssh, but still get the same error. It's interesting to know that tensorflow use X, even though running in the command line?

Comment: I also think it shouldn't, but who knows what happens underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `matplotlib` in your tensorflow training code?

If your answer is yes, you can try to add the following lines in your code.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```